# Intrinsic derivative exercise confusion

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I was told to compute $$\frac{\delta S_{\alpha}}{\delta t}$$ this equals $$\frac{\delta S_{\alpha}}{\delta t}=\frac{dS_{\alpha}(S,t)}{dt}-V^{\gamma}\Gamma^{\omega}_{\gamma\beta}S_{\omega}$$ $$=\frac{dS_\alpha}{dS^\beta}\frac{dS^\beta}{dt}-V^{\gamma}\Gamma^{\omega}_{\gamma\beta}S_{\omega}$$ $$=(\nabla_{\beta}S_\alpha+\Gamma^{\omega}_{\alpha\beta}S_{\omega})V^{\beta}-V^{\gamma}\Gamma^{\omega}_{\gamma\beta}S_{\omega}$$ $$=\nabla_{\beta}S_{\alpha}V^\beta+V^{\beta}\Gamma^{\omega}_{\alpha\beta}S_{\omega}-V^{\gamma}\Gamma^{\omega}_{\gamma\beta}S_{\omega}$$ $$=\nabla_{\beta}S_{\alpha}V^{\beta}$$ $$=NB_{\alpha\beta}V^\beta$$ $$=NV^{\beta}B_{\alpha\beta}$$. My question is what is the $$S_\alpha$$term, is it a tensor, vector field? The book did not specify what it was.

Comment: What is the book you are reading?

Comment: introduction to tensor analysis and the calculus of moving surfaces by Pavel Grinfeld.

Comment: Given the word "surfaces" in the book title and the way ?you? are using it in manipulations I'd say that $\mathbf{S}_\alpha$ is the *surface* covariant basis. Notice that the elements of this tensor are *vectors*. In that case $B_{\alpha\beta}$ in the expression $\nabla_{\alpha}\mathbf{S}_\beta=\mathbf{N}B_{\alpha\beta}$ is t*he extrinsic curvature tensor* and $\mathbf{N}$ is the normal. But you really need to explain your setting in waaaay more detail to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Contra. The question vaguely said  "Compute $$S_\alpha$$ without specifying what the object really is. Thanks for clearing things up, it makes a lot more sense.